# how to resolve a json object to get the data in the page using backbone

Tags: json, object, backbone.js

I'm using backbone.
I have a json data like:

```
{"status": 7, 
 "organizations":[{"org_address":"\u4e2d\u56fd\u5317\u4eac\u5e02\u671d\u9633\u95e8\u59161001\u53f7", "job_positions": ["\u526f\u603b"], "org_id": 6, "org_name": "\u6570\u7ef4\u7f51\u7edc"}], "first_name": null, "last_name": null, "create_date": "2013-06-26 16:29:44.314000", "name": "\u66f9\u4f1f", "extra_emails": [null], "tags": [["friend"]], "nick_name": "\u4f11\u606f\u4e00\u4f1a\u513f", "gender": "\u7537", "image": null, "created_by": "system", "effective_start_date": "2013-06-26 16:29:44.314000", "social_medias": [{"url": "http://weibo.com/12345", "party_rel_id": 5, "type": "\u65b0\u6d6a\u5fae\u535a", "party_id": null, "sm_id": "\u6570\u636e\u5e93\u4e13\u5bb6"}], "date_of_birth": "1980-04-01", "extra_phones": {"office_phone": "82323333", "fax": "82324433"}, "mobile_phone": "17782272211", "primary_email": "weic@xy.com", "id": "5", "isUser": false}
```

---

my backbone model is:

```
var ContactDetail = Backbone.Model.extend({  
    urlRoot: URL_CONTACTS1+"3/5"
});

var ContactDetailCollection =  Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
    model: ContactDetail,
    url: URL_CONTACTS1+"3/5"
})
```

my backbone view is:

```
var ContactDetailItemView = Backbone.View.extend({
    tagName: 'div', 
    tagClass: 'border',
    template: _.template($('#contactdetail-template').html()),  
        render: function() {
        this.$el.html( this.template(this.model.toJSON()));
        return this;
    }
});
var ContactDetailListView =  Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#main'),
    initialize:  function(){
        this.listenTo(this.collection, 'reset', this.render);
    },  

        render: function() {
            this.$el.empty(); 
            this.collection.each( function( $model ) {
            var itemview = new ContactDetailItemView({model: $model}); 
        this.$el.append( itemview.render().el );  
            }, this);
        return this;
    },
})
```

the entrance is:

```
ContactDetailManagePageModel.prototype.init = function(){ 
    var myContactDetails = new ContactDetailCollection();
    contactDetailListView = new ContactDetailListView({
            collection: myContactDetails
        });     
    myContactDetails.fetch({reset:true});
}
```

In the html,I get data like this:

```
<tr>
   <td><span class="Name_text"><%=name%></span>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<%=primary_email%></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><%=mobile_phone%></td>
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <td><%=org_address%></td>
 </tr>
```

But I can't get the data named "org_address",which is in object "organizations" in the json data,it said that the "org_address" is not defined.

Hope for your help.Thanks!

Comment: You can do something like <%=organizations[0].org_address%>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you pass in a data object to an underscore template, underscore will [resolve](http://underscorejs.org/#template) the objects properties to it's *free variables*, if one of those properties is in turn an array or itself an object you can access it just as you would in regular JavaScript using dot or bracket notation.

So for example with your JSON, since organizations is an array and it's first element contains the property org_address you can simply do the following to get the org_address

```
<%=organizations[0].org_address%>
```

You are also able to execute JavaScript code in your template, so if for example organizations contained an array of multiple organizations you could loop through them and print them all out. For example

```
<%  for (var i = 0, len = organizations.length; i < len; i++) { %>
     <tr><td>organizations[i].org_address</td></tr>
<% } %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `<%= organizations[0].org_address%>`